# I'm trying to trade BTCUSD via "unofficial" Robinhood APIs using Python. I'm getting an index error when accessing api.robinhood.com/instruments

Tags: python

BTCUSD is not found in this url, so an empty list is being returned, causing the index error.  Is there a different url I should be using for BTCUSD?

Comment: What url are you referring to?

Comment: api.robinhood.com/instruments

Comment: I'm not familiar with Robinhood APIs, but where is it documented that _any_ crypto uses that API URL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.